# how to create a newsletter in Microsoft outlook with images background

Tags: email, outlook, gmail

I would like to ask if a message can be made by a Outlook, so I put a picture as a background and write the content of the message above it, knowing it must be compatible with Gmail and Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty bullet-proof solution:

```
<table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600" style="margin: 0 auto;" class="email-container">
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" style="text-align: center; background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/600x230/222222/666666'); background-color: #222222; background-position: center center !important; background-size: cover !important;">
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:175px; background-position: center center !important;">
        <v:fill type="tile" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x230/222222/666666" color="#222222" />
        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
        <![endif]-->
        <div>
            <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="middle" style="text-align: center; padding: 40px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #ffffff;">
                        <p style="margin: 0;">Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent laoreet malesuada cursus. Maecenas scelerisque congue eros eu posuere. Praesent in felis ut velit pretium lobortis rhoncus ut&nbsp;erat.</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        </v:textbox>
        </v:rect>
        <![endif]-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

- Bulletproof Background Images: https://backgrounds.cm
- Email template: https://tedgoas.github.io/Cerberus/